# Accessing to PostgreSQL array via ScalikeJDBC

Tags: arrays, postgresql, scala, data-access-layer, scalikejdbc

I try use ScalikeJDBC for access to array in PostgreSQL 9.4. DDL:

```
create table itab (
        code varchar primary key,
        group_list varchar[]
);
```

A simple case class and loader are defined in Scala application.

```
case class Item(code: String, groupSet: List[String])

trait loader {
  def loadAllItems: List[Item] = {
      insideReadOnly { implicit session =>
                       sql"select CODE, GROUP_LIST from ITAB"
                       .map(e => Item(
                           e.string("code"),
                           e.array("group_list").asInstanceOf[Buffer[String]]
                        )).list.apply()
                     }
  }
}
```

When I run an application I get runtime exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
```

How can I resolve it?
Thanks. Hoviman.

Comment: perhaps if you invoke `.getArray()` before casting, it'll work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `rs.array("group_list").getArray.asInstanceOf[Array[String]]`

It's just java.sql.Array underneath

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Now a compiler scolds type mismatching: found Array[String] but List[String] is required. When I change type of Item.groupSet on Array[String] there is no any compile or runtime error, but I get a result as a String, not as an Array[String].

Comment: It looks like scalikejdbc returns PostgreSQL varchar[] as a simple string, but not as an array of strings. Am I right? And if not, should I use implicit conversion by string interpolation?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. toList works correctly ;)

```
e.array("group_list").getArray.asInstanceOf[Array[String]].toList
```